# how to show original file structure in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I imported [seldon-core](https://github.com/josephglanville/seldon-core/tree/34ab0c33c55879ebe3ea3009ca64b0b47d18896c) to intellij, which tried to separate the files to different projects automatically.

[image]

How to disable this? I need to view all the files in original/same structure with the git repo, like:

[image]

Thanks

**UPDATE**

It STILL DOES NOT work now even I did the following:

When importing project, we need choose `Project format` as `.ipr (file based)`.

[image]

Then, we need select `Project Files`

[image]

Comment: Try adding a new module for the project root: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#add-new-module.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching between the options under `projects`? There is an option with `project files`

[image]

`Project Files` shows the exact file structure as your git repo.

Comment: I used `Project files`, which does not work.
And I did not see `Project source files` in my intellij.